# URL as a key, HTML page as content - HBase, Hive, or another DB

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

I need a simple storage where I want to store HTML page content. Basically downloaded HTML page code. URL will be the key.  We have installed  Hortonworks HDP  2.6.3 cluster.
Which one is more suitable: HBase, Hive?
HBase has row access by key. But since URL as the key I afraid data will be all over the place.
Hive data can be accessed with where clause but I am not sure how fast it will be since there is no index.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can query Hbase with Hive....

Comment: Hive also is not a database. It's a processing engine.  Your HDP cluster requires a MySQL or Postgres database for Hive, Ambari, and Oozie, so Hbase and Hive aren't your only options, anyway

Comment: @cricket_007 I know and understand that.  But in order to store for direct access by URL which one is better?

Comment: Software recommendations are off opic for Stackoverflow, but you seem to understand that Hbase is better than Hive, and putting an index on a relational database would be good also

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. We wont to get away from relational DBs.

Comment: What you need is a key value store, but HDP doesn't come with one

Comment: @cricket_007 I saw Accumulo  1.7.0    Robust, scalable, high performance distributed key/value store.  Looks like it is similar to HBase.

Comment: Forgot about that one. I don't have any experience with it